# How to change the code for 1 piece drag and drop to a number of pieces?

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop

I am working on some jigsaw puzzles for children on the iPad.

This code is working fine for 16 pieces, but it is a lot of code and i am wondering how to change the code so it will be less coding. Hope someone can help me with this.

```
p1.visible = true;
p2.visible = true;

p1.x = 60;
p1.y = 164;
p1.scaleX = 0.80;
p1.scaleY = 0.80;

p2.x = 842;
p2.y = 310;
p2.scaleX = 0.80;
p2.scaleY = 0.80;


p1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag_piece);
p1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_piece);
p2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag_piece);
p2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_piece);


function drag_piece(e: MouseEvent): void {
        current_piece = MovieClip(e.currentTarget);
        if(current_piece == p1){
            target_piece = t1;
        }
        if(current_piece == p2){
            target_piece = t2;
        }
        current_piece.startDrag();
}

function stop_piece(e: MouseEvent): void {

    current_piece.stopDrag();

    if (target_piece.hitTestObject(current_piece)) {
            current_piece.scaleX = 1;
            current_piece.scaleY = 1;
            current_piece.x = target_piece.x;
            current_piece.y = target_piece.y;
            counter = counter +1;
            trace('piece is in place', counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect case for learning about and using Classes. Lots of examples and tutorials out there. (like: http://www.kirupa.com/developer/as3/classes_as3_pg1.htm and http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/learn/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f36.html

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you are asking but this doesn't look like a lot of code at all. Are you saying the code before the `drag_piece` handler is repeated for 16 pieces, in other words you have `p16.visible = true`, etc?

Comment: How are the coordinates of each piece determined? Do they follow a pattern, for example equally spaced within a rectangular area? (You didn't post enough code to tell.)

Comment: @Aaron I repeat the code for p1 16 times and wrote 16 addEventListeners and 16 drag functions. The pieces are on the board left and right of the puzzle and the targets are in place on the puzzle. The coordinates of the targets can be used when the piece hits the target, to put the piece in place.

Comment: Thanks for the code with the Array that minimizes the 16 addEventListeners to just 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, put all your pieces in an array so they can be looped over:

```
var pieces:Array = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12, p13, p14, p15, p16];
```

Now you can loop over the pieces and apply common code to all of them:

```
for each(var piece:MovieClip in pieces){
    piece.visible = true;
    piece.scaleX = 0.80;
    piece.scaleY = 0.80;
    piece.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag_piece);
    piece.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_piece);
}
```

---

> I have the initial pieces on the stage with x and y specified in the
>   code so when the puzzle starts for the second time, all pieces are
>   again on the original stage position so that the puzzle can be made
>   again.

If I understand, you can loop over the pieces when the game loads for the first time and store their original positions:

```
// store original positions of pieces
for each(var piece:MovieClip in pieces){
    piece.originalX = piece.x;
    piece.originalY = piece.y;
}
```

(Tip: `MovieClip` is [*dynamic*](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f89.html), which allows any custom properties to be assigned to it, in this case `originalX` and `originalY`. Most other classes in AS3 are *sealed* and do not allow this, so you would have to extend the class or store the values in a separate place.)

Now when you want to "reset" the pieces, you can just loop over the pieces and set their `x,y` position to the `originalX,originalY` position:

```
// reset pieces to original positions
for each(var piece:MovieClip in pieces){
    piece.x = piece.originalX;
    piece.y = piece.originalY;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so far, this is working fine for the puzzle. Still trying to optimize the coding. I have the initial pieces on the stage with x and y specified in the code so when the puzzle starts for the second time, all pieces are again on the original stage position so that the puzzle can be made again.

Comment: I updated my answer with some thoughts on the positioning of pieces.

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks for the update. I see what you mean and that is precisely what I would like to do, but I am not sure how to do it. I studied a class tutorial but can not see how to make that work for a puzzle piece. Do you have a tip on where to look?

Comment: The example I posted doesn't actually use any class code. The classes I refer to are all built-in AS3 classes you are already using. You can just put that code on the timeline if you want. Did you try putting that code anywhere? What happened?

Comment: I put the code in and yes it worked! At first I didn't understand that all these positions were actually stored as attributes of all these pieces without placing them in some sort of container or array. The code is decreased from 2500 lines to less than 500 now.

Comment: I am still looking for an easy way to make the comparison of the piece with the target.    if(current_piece == p1){target_piece = t1;} I have this 16 times as well. I tried to retrieve the number out of the current piece and put it in a string variable but it does not compare with the MovieClip symbol.

Comment: Since I put this all in place now I have 3 working puzzles with 500 lines of code. So thank you for your help so far. I would rather learn now how I can put this for 1 puzzle in a class and make 20 puzzles without copying all the code again and again...

Comment: You could extract the target from the current piece name like this: `var targetName:String = "t" + piece.name.substr(1)` and you can access it from parent timeline using array brackets, ex if `this` is the timeline that holds the targets: `this[targetName]`. What I would prefer to do is assign a `target` to each `piece` in the initial loop.

Comment: Yes, using classes here would be more elegant. You would probably need at least two classes: `Puzzle` and `Piece`. Another option to avoid copy/paste is to use [`include`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#include)